# query for disallow countries

Tags: php, mysql

Mysql & Php question: So I have two tables (users & settings) and the structure of them are:

```
==> table_users
---->userid (10001)
---->username (miketyson)
---->usercountry (us)

==> table_settings
---->userkey (10002)
---->disallowcountries (us)
```

So what is the query if the user "miketyson" do login and all records from users who disallowed the same country from "miketyson" are be to not display? (Because the user 10002 disallow users from country "us").

Comment: So `miketyson` logs in .. what does he see?

Comment: he see all users excepted they who disallowed the country wich `miketyson` are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    userkey
FROM
    table_settings
    LEFT JOIN table_users ON (
        username = 'miketyson'
        AND disallowcountries = usercountry
    )
WHERE
    userid IS NULL
```